# Office.js (Word 2016) ContentControl getOoxml/insertOoxml

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I have a word 2016 document with a number of content controls on the page. I save each content control by using .getOoxml and saving the xml string to the database.

I can then refresh the content control by reading out the string and using insertOoxml. This works for most things but bullet points keep losing their format. For example if I save something like this:

- Bullet A
- Bullet B
- Bullet C

when I refresh it it comes back like this

1. Bullet A
2. Bullet B
3. Bullet C

I have also taken the xml that getOoxml produces and opened it directly with word and it also loses the format.

Is this a bug with the getOoxml api for the content control or is there something I can do to fix this?

I'm not sure if it is directly related to the issue I have but I saw a similar issue on GiHub (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/272) that appears unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known issue and the fix was shipped with our May fork shipped since July 5th to the public. (Build 16.0.7070.2022+). Please make sure you have the latest update. Please reply with your current build number as well, just to triple check. thanks so much and happy coding!!!

Comment: I was on the "Deferred" channel for office updates so my version was (16.0.6741.2048). I just switched to use the "Current" channel (16.0.7070.2028) and my issue has been fixed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: great!!!! thanks! The deferred channel will be updated with the fix on its next release.